# Creating SKSpriteNode from SKTexture using pixeldata

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sktexture

I'm trying to create a SKSpriteNode from a 2D-Array of RGBA objects which represents the pixels in a image I want to create. But I don't know how to do it, and I searched for tutorials and could not find one.

**For example:**

```
struct RGBA {
    var r: UInt8
    var g: UInt8
    var b: UInt8
    var a: UInt8
}

let pixelData: [[RGBA]] = ...

function CreateSKSpriteNodeFromPixelData(data: [[RGBA]]) -> SKSpriteNode {
    //......What goes on here?
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create texture from RGBA pixel data and use it as constructor parameter for SKSpriteNode.

```
let texture = SKTexture(data: pixelData, size: pixelDataSize)
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
```

[SKTexture reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTexture/textureWithData:size:)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!